# Twsist effect (glRotatef) for the blade doesn't work

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am trying to create a twist effect (not rotate) for the blade but it doesn't work at all. In particular, I am trying to use `glRotatef` function to rotate the axis and make it appear as blade is twisting.

Any help would be great.

[image]

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PI 3.14159265

static GLfloat lpos[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 1.0 };
static GLfloat white[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
static GLfloat black[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
static GLfloat red[] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
static GLfloat yellow[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
static float alpha = 0.0;
static float beta = PI / 6.0;
static float zoom = 10.0;
static bool lightSource = true;
float twistConstant = 0;
float rotateConstant = 0;
float numberOfObj = 3;
float numberOfTriangles = 1;
static GLdouble cpos[3];



void DrawTopTriangleSet(){
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, yellow);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, yellow);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

    for (int i = 180; i >= 0; i = i - numberOfTriangles){
        if (i > 90){
            glPushMatrix();
            glLoadIdentity();
            glRotatef(i, 1, 0, 0);
            glPopMatrix();
        }
        glNormal3f(0, sin(PI / 4 + twistConstant), cos(PI / 4 + twistConstant - PI / 4));
        glVertex3f(i*PI / 180, 0, 0.5*sin(i*PI / 180));
        glVertex3f(i*PI / 180, 0.5*sin(i*PI / 180), twistConstant*-sin(i*PI / 180));
    }
    glEnd();
}

void DrawBottomTriangleSet(){
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, yellow);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, yellow);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

    for (int i = 180; i >= 0; i = i - numberOfTriangles){
        if (i > 90){
            glPushMatrix();
            glLoadIdentity();
            glRotatef(i, 1, 0, 0);
            glPopMatrix();
        }
        glNormal3f(0, -sin(PI / 4 + twistConstant), cos(PI / 4 + twistConstant - PI / 4));
        glVertex3f(i*PI / 180, -0.5*sin(i*PI / 180), twistConstant*sin(i*PI / 180));
        glVertex3f(i*PI / 180, 0, 0.5*sin(i*PI / 180));
    }

    glEnd();
}

void DrawBackTriangleSet(){
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, yellow);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, yellow);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);


    for (int i = 180; i >= 0; i = i - numberOfTriangles){
        if (i > 90){
            glPushMatrix();
            glLoadIdentity();
            glRotatef(i, 1, 0, 0);
            glPopMatrix();
        }
        glNormal3f(0, 5 * sin(PI - twistConstant), 5 * cos(PI - twistConstant));
        glVertex3f(i*PI / 180, 0.5*sin(i*PI / 180), twistConstant*-sin(i*PI / 180));
        glVertex3f(i*PI / 180, -0.5*sin(i*PI / 180), twistConstant*sin(i*PI / 180));
    }
    glEnd();

}

void DrawInsideTriangleSet(){
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

    for (int i = 180; i >= 0; i = i - numberOfTriangles){
        if (i > 90){
            glPushMatrix();
            glLoadIdentity();
            glRotatef(i, 1, 0, 0);
            glPopMatrix();
        }
        glVertex3f(i*PI / 180, 0.5*sin(i*PI / 180), twistConstant*-sin(i*PI / 180));
        glVertex3f(i*PI / 180, 0, 0.5*sin(i*PI / 180));
        glVertex3f(i*PI / 180, -0.5*sin(i*PI / 180), twistConstant*sin(i*PI / 180));
    }

    glEnd();
}

void writemessage()
{
    printf(" X => x++ <= Move light source in direction of +X\n");
    printf(" Y => y++ <= Move light source in direction of +Y\n");
    printf(" Z => z++ <= Move light source in direction of +Z\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("^X => x-- <= Move light source in direction of -X\n");
    printf("^Y => y-- <= Move light source in direction of -Y\n");
    printf("^Z => z-- <= Move light source in direction of -Z\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" ^ => Move camera up\n");
    printf(" > => Move camera right\n");
    printf(" < => Move camera left\n");
    printf(" down arrow => Move camera down\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" t => More Twist\n");
    printf(" f => Less Twist\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" q => More Propeller\n");
    printf(" f => Less Propeller\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" w => More Triangles\n");
    printf(" s => Less Triangles\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" 0 => Toggling light source\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" r => Rotates Propeller\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" You can not move the light source when the light source is off !!!");
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 0.01, 20.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    cpos[0] = zoom * cos(beta) * sin(alpha);
    cpos[1] = zoom * sin(beta);
    cpos[2] = zoom * cos(beta) * cos(alpha);
    gluLookAt(cpos[0], cpos[1], cpos[2], 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    if (lightSource == true){
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lpos);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, white);
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(lpos[0], lpos[1], lpos[2]);
        glutSolidSphere(0.1, 10, 8);
        glPopMatrix();
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    }
    glRotatef(rotateConstant, 0, 0, 1);


    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObj; i++){
        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(i * 360 / numberOfObj, 0, 0, 1);

        DrawTopTriangleSet();
        DrawBottomTriangleSet();
        DrawBackTriangleSet();
        DrawInsideTriangleSet();

        glPopMatrix();
    }


    // Cone
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, red);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, red);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(0, 0, -1.5);
    glutSolidCone(1, 2, 50, 50);
    glPopMatrix();

    // Back of Cone
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_EMISSION, black);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, red);
    glMaterialfv(GL_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, red);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i++)
    {
        glVertex3f(cos(i*PI / 180) * 1, sin(i*PI / 180) * 1, -1.5);
    }

    glEnd();


    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();
}


void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key) {
    case 27:
        exit(0);
        break;
    case 'x':
        if (lightSource == true)
            lpos[0] = lpos[0] + 0.2;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'X':
        if (lightSource == true)
            lpos[0] = lpos[0] - 0.2;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'y':
        if (lightSource == true)
            lpos[1] = lpos[1] + 0.2;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'Y':
        if (lightSource == true)
            lpos[1] = lpos[1] - 0.2;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'z':
        if (lightSource == true)
            lpos[2] = lpos[2] + 0.2;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 'Z':
        if (lightSource == true)
            lpos[2] = lpos[2] - 0.2;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;

    case '+':
        if (zoom != 1.5)zoom = zoom - 0.5;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case '-':
        if (zoom != 15)zoom = zoom + 0.5;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case '0':
        if (lightSource == true){
            glDisable(GL_LIGHT0);
            lightSource = false;
        }
        else{
            glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
            lightSource = true;
        }
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 't':
        if (twistConstant <= PI/4){
            twistConstant = twistConstant + 0.05;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }
        break;
    case 'f':
        if (twistConstant >= 0){
            twistConstant = twistConstant - 0.05;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }
        break;
    case 'r':
        rotateConstant = rotateConstant + 2;
        glutPostRedisplay();

        break;
    case 'q':
        if (numberOfObj <= 6){
            numberOfObj++;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }

        break;
    case 'a':
        if (numberOfObj >= 0){
            numberOfObj--;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }

        break;
    case 's':
        if (numberOfTriangles <90){
            numberOfTriangles++;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }

        break;
    case 'w':
        if (numberOfTriangles > 1){
            numberOfTriangles--;
            glutPostRedisplay();
        }

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}


void specialkey(GLint key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key) {
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        alpha = alpha + PI / 180;
        if (alpha > 2 * PI) alpha = alpha - 2 * PI;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        alpha = alpha - PI / 180;
        if (alpha < 0) alpha = alpha + 2 * PI;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        if (beta < 0.45*PI) beta = beta + PI / 180;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
        if (beta > -0.05*PI) beta = beta - PI / 180;
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;


    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    writemessage();
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(1200, 800);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_TRUE);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutSpecialFunc(specialkey);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only a limited set of OpenGL calls that are valid between `glBegin()` and `glEnd()`. Commands that modify the current transformation are not among them. The full list of valid calls, copied from the [`glBegin()` man page](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBegin.xml):

> Only a subset of GL commands can be used between glBegin and glEnd. The commands are glVertex, glColor, glSecondaryColor, glIndex, glNormal, glFogCoord, glTexCoord, glMultiTexCoord, glVertexAttrib, glEvalCoord, glEvalPoint, glArrayElement, glMaterial, and glEdgeFlag. Also, it is acceptable to use glCallList or glCallLists to execute display lists that include only the preceding commands. If any other GL command is executed between glBegin and glEnd, the error flag is set and the command is ignored.

Whenever something does not work as expected with your OpenGL calls, you should try calling `glGetError()` to see if it flags any errors. In this case, you would see `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` errors for the invalid calls.

Since you can't change the transformation in the middle of a primitive, it's best to simply apply the rotation needed for the twisting effect to your points as you calculate them. Say you want a twist around the x-axis, and you calculated `x`, `y` and `z` without the twist, you would then use something like:

```
float twistAng = someFactor * x;
float twistCos = cos(twistAng);
float twistSin = sin(twistAng);
float yTwisted = twistCos * y - twistSin * z;
float zTwisted = twistSin * y + twistCos * z;
```

Then you use `(x, yTwisted, zTwisted)` as your vertex.